# Do I need to install nodejs mongodb driver to use in node apps when I have mongoDB installed on my computer?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I installed mongoDB on my computer but again while working with node.js do i need to install node.js mongoDB driver through "npm install mongodb"?

Comment: Driver is to interact with your mongodb installation, if you want to interact with the database you'll have to use the driver.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to connect and interact with your database, I would recommend mongoose. You can install it with `npm install mongoose`. To get starte, read the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install mongodb enterprise version you can also download mongodb comapss which comes with gui db to interact with your collection whithout using cli which is great. You can download it from here: https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass Just download as it is donot go for custom one as it includes mongodb server and other things you might required.